# PHP Codeception with Docker

Tags: php, docker

Hi I am new to the Docker world and I am trying to come up with a directive that would

1. Installs composer
2. and a volume mapping so i don't have to copy the source code

so far i have this:

```
FROM php:5.6-cli
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is docker image for composer in dockerhub

https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/~/dockerfile/

For volume mount you need to do when you run the image.

```
docker run -v host_dir:/container_dir image_name
```